# How to filter entities based on list of items in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to filter records base on predicate in asp.net core.

I have using LinqKit package to build predicate
My predicate builder:

```
  Expression<Func<Language, bool>> whereClause = null;
            if (model.search != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.search.value))
                {
                    List<string> searchTerms = model.search.value.Split(',').ToList().ConvertAll(x => x.ToLower());
                    whereClause = BuildDynamicWhereClause(searchTerms);
                }
            }
```

Private method return predicate:

```
 private Expression<Func<Language, bool>> BuildDynamicWhereClause(List<string> searchTerms)
        {
            ExpressionStarter<Language> predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Language>();
            predicate = predicate.Or(x => searchTerms.Any(srch => x.Name.Contains(srch)));


            return predicate;
        }
```

My Query:

```
 List<LanguageModel> result = (from x in _repo.Filter(whereClause)
                                          select new LanguageModel
                                          {
                                              Id = x.Id,
                                              Name = x.Name,
                                              Key = x.Key,
                                              Image = x.Image,
                                          }).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

my Filter method:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Filter(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
 
            if (predicate != null)
            {
                return  query.Where(predicate).ToList();
 
            }
            else
            {
                return _dbSet;
            }
           
        }
```

When I passing predicate to filter records `query = query.Where(predicate);` this line throw exception like:

```
 The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Language>()
    .Where(l => __searchTerms_0
        .Any(srch => l.Name.Contains(srch)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

I was try to resolve this but it not working, If you have any way to do this please let me know or please let me know for better way to filter records in **asp.net core 5** or **asp.net core 3.1**

Comment: It's obvious. You have wrong predicate which is not shown in  the question. Even you post it here -  EF do not support such search condition.

Comment: Better update your question: How to filter entities based on list of items.

Comment: The problem is in the argument value, which you haven't included.

Comment: None of the code you posted is relevant. The issue is the expression you are passing that cannot be translated to SQL. Please delete the code you have posted and instead show the query expression that cannot be translated. Also change the title to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: Added fully example code to understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, filter creation should be improved:

```cs
private Expression<Func<Language, bool>> BuildDynamicWhereClause(List<string> searchTerms)
{
    predicate = ExpressionHelpers.CreateFilterByItems<Language, string>(
        searchTerms, 
        (x, srch) => x.Name.Contains(srch), 
        true);
    return predicate;
}
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class ExpressionHelpers
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateFilterByItems<T, TItem>(IEnumerable<TItem> items,
        Expression<Func<T, TItem, bool>> filterPattern, bool isOr)
    {
        Expression predicate = null;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemExpr = Expression.Constant(item);
            var itemCondition = ExpressionReplacer.Replace(filterPattern.Body, filterPattern.Parameters[1], itemExpr);
            if (predicate == null)
                predicate = itemCondition;
            else
            {
                predicate = Expression.MakeBinary(isOr ? ExpressionType.OrElse : ExpressionType.AndAlso, predicate,
                    itemCondition);
            }
        }

        predicate ??= Expression.Constant(false);
        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, filterPattern.Parameters[0]);

        return filterLambda;
    }

   class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly IDictionary<Expression, Expression> _replaceMap;

        public ExpressionReplacer(IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            _replaceMap = replaceMap ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaceMap));
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression exp)
        {
            if (exp != null && _replaceMap.TryGetValue(exp, out var replacement))
                return replacement;
            return base.Visit(exp);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, Expression toReplace, Expression toExpr)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { toReplace, toExpr } }).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(replaceMap).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression lambda, params Expression[] toReplace)
        {
            if (lambda.Parameters.Count != toReplace.Length)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return new ExpressionReplacer(Enumerable.Range(0, lambda.Parameters.Count)
                .ToDictionary(i => (Expression) lambda.Parameters[i], i => toReplace[i])).Visit(lambda.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may change your `BuildDynamicWhereClause` method like this:

```
private Expression<Func<Language, bool>> BuildDynamicWhereClause(List<string> searchTerms)
{
    ExpressionStarter<Language> predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Language>();
    foreach (var item in searchTerms)
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Name.Contains(item));
    }
    return predicate;
}
```